# it's print html for me but i want him to print the resbon for me

Tags: python, python-requests, payload

please fix this problem for me it's print html text for me but i want him to print the resbon for me

the code
import requests,json
url=('https://api.opensea.io/graphql/')
hed={
'accept': '*/*',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'authorization': 'JWT',
'content-length': '204',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'cookie': 'csrftoken=0QsXGzaeSJSKvYGd9aRTQVq7jWWOIpSy6wvwBpDRn2pK3WKwCxkeeKcH8WLPEK4W; __cf_bm=noBFWZQBJGF5_1n6CaDdjs17wv896.exY_FDTnEC1dU-1645954415-0-AbXYdnig4DyTbdEVSRMN5CnnLW9A7MtetoE8YEiy6Y7Rzn4DT/elvk/fjPr6vBRxUuv3LYardOJPPrdceHF/dkY=; amp_ddd6ec=-RffiW6t4AxE9_A_Eg7GWR...1fst7hcr1.1fst8opd0.k.1.l',
'origin': 'https://opensea.io',
'referer': 'https://opensea.io/',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
'sec-gpc': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
'x-api-key': '2f6f419a083c46de9d83ce3dbe7db601',
'x-build-id': 'sJ2yOKDaJSxeSQoRzRnai',
'x-signed-query': '1632dfddbebd2a64cf8a0920a11b5f4927fd2d1556bcacd4ab31771130e538bb',
'x-viewer-address': ';',}

```
data={"id": "useUsernameInputQuery",
"query": "query useUsernameInputQuery(\n  $username: String!\n) {\n  account(identity: {username: $username}) {\n    address\n    id\n  }\n}\n",
"variables": "{username: 'alqe'}",
"{username}": "alqe"}
req=requests.post(url=url,headers=hed,json=data)
print(req.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ":" from the keys in your headers.
`":method"` becomes `"method"` and so on.

Comment: Are those headers even needed? The authority, scheme + path are part of the url and requests post method is being used

Comment: I don't think they are needed in this case.